# Syntax Error in showing Error Description

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is the correct Syntax to be applied for "@[System::ErrorDescription]" inside the query like "INSERT" ? I am unable to retrieve the correct Error Description inside the table, as the result in the table is showing as "@[System::ErrorDescription]". I am not getting the result !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a command like:

```
INSERT YourTable (errordesc) SELECT ?
```

And then put a parameter called 1 in, populated with @[System::ErrorDescription]

Comment: what is the correct format which includes the parameter 1 which you mentioned about ??

Comment: Have a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx for more info on how to use parameters, because it depends slightly on what type of connection you have. But basically, go to the Parameter Mapping tab, and put it in there.

Comment: Hi Aaron - what are you trying to use it on?